# My external monitor doesn't display

Tags: graphics, display, monitor

Whilst I was working today, my external monitor suddenly indicated "no signal"

I have tried all these

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa -y
sudo apt update
ubuntu-drivers devices

sudo apt install nvidia-driver-535
sudo reboot
```

None of them have worked.

Any ideas on what to do next?

Ubuntu 22.04

Graphics : Nvidia RTX 3050ti

Comment: Check the cable connection. "No signal" means the monitor has stopped hearing electrical signals from your video driver hardware.

Comment: Its not a hardware issue, I suppose. It connects via Windows

Comment: Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/review/suggested-edits/1313277) your question and add more details of your system.  What version of Ubuntu are you running?  What is your hardware, i.e. video card?  Was there anything you had to do special the first time to make the external monitor work?  The reason I ask this is that I have a Compaq laptop and the drivers do not install properly on it and there is a lot of tweaking you have to do to the config files just so that the display works properly.  Right now all we can do is guess.

Comment: Thank you, I just edited it.

Comment: Have you checked the Monitors in setting to see if it sees multiple monitors in there?